# How can my Mac route to the Raspberry Pi with the command?

Tags: wifi, ssh, dns

I was following the tutorial saying that I can connect to the Raspberry Pi with SSH by entering the simple following command:

```
$ ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

But I didn't set the host `raspberrypi.local`. I think this is related the the DNS but I don't know where I need to start from.

Comment: The Pi is set up to use bonjour/zeroconf on Raspbian. This thread should answer most questions https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=18207 Does SSH work? If not are you using a mac or PC? If a PC is itunes installed? Are you using Raspbian? How is the Pi connected to the network?

Comment: Thank you very much. It gives me a lot of hints I was looking for.

Comment: bonjour/zeroconf is often related to packages bearing an `avahi-` prefix moniker!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Mac, or a PC (with iTunes installed) you can use the .local hostname (`raspberrypi.local`) to reach your Pi via SSH, a browser or anywhere a domain name is required, without having configured DNS or `/etc/hosts` entries.

This is not magic, but an implementation of Zeroconf (aka Bonjour) which allows automatic discovery of servers and systems on a local area network (LAN).

The following links will give you additional details:

- [Bonjour (Zeroconf) Networking for Windows and Linux](https://learn.adafruit.com/bonjour-zeroconf-networking-for-windows-and-linux/overview)
- [How (and Why) to Assign the .local Domain to Your Raspberry Pi](http://www.howtogeek.com/167190/how-and-why-to-assign-the-.local-domain-to-your-raspberry-pi/)
- [FYI: Bonjour / Zeroconf on Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=18207)

Note: in the event of a name collision (e.g. a second Pi with a hostname of `raspberrypi`) the second Pi will have a number appended to the hostname (e.g. `raspberrypi2.local`).